# Iterate or scan through multiple arrays in python

Tags: python, loops

Say if I had multiple arrays in python. For example,

```
r1 = [a1[0], a2[0], a3[0], a4[0], a5[0], a6[0], a7[0], a8[0], a9[0]]
r2 = [a1[1], a2[1], a3[1], a4[1], a5[1], a6[1], a7[1], a8[1], a9[1]]
r3 = [a1[2], a2[2], a3[2], a4[2], a5[2], a6[2], a7[2], a8[2], a9[2]]
r4 = [a1[3], a2[3], a3[3], a4[3], a5[3], a6[3], a7[3], a8[3], a9[3]]
r5 = [a1[4], a2[4], a3[4], a4[4], a5[4], a6[4], a7[4], a8[4], a9[4]]
r6 = [a1[5], a2[5], a3[5], a4[5], a5[5], a6[5], a7[5], a8[5], a9[5]]
r7 = [a1[6], a2[6], a3[6], a4[6], a5[6], a6[6], a7[6], a8[6], a9[6]]
r8 = [a1[7], a2[7], a3[7], a4[7], a5[7], a6[7], a7[7], a8[7], a9[7]]
r9 = [a1[8], a2[8], a3[8], a4[8], a5[8], a6[8], a7[8], a8[8], a9[8]]
```

This makes a grid of numbers, but is there a way to scan through all of these lists? So far I sort of came up with this pseudocode:

```
"for x in multiple lists" 
     if any element at any of the r lists of the list ==0
     Do something
```

Comment: That's not valid python.

Comment: Look at `zip`. It will make your life enormously easier.

Comment: `chain` from itertools may also be handy

Comment: Are you using that kind of data structure because of an assignment requirement, or are you open to using something else to make it easier? If so you should check out `numpy`

Answer (score 2):

You an use a nested generator expression within built in function `any()` for that aim:

```
if any(item == 0 for sub_list in r_lists for item in sub_lists):
      # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate:

```
list_of_lists = [r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9]
for row in list_of_lists:
    if any(element == 0 for element in row):
        do_something()
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a two-dimensional array really. Not sure, what you are trying to do, maybe this will help: https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html ??